# Gamma matrices and special relativity

Tags: clifford-algebras

I understand how gamma matrices generate a Clifford algebra that corresponds to the Minkowski metric. So the next step for me is to understand how gamma matrices are used in the context of special relativity. I've been Googling but all I get is stuff about quantum mechanics. The quantum mechanics stuff is going to have to wait. Any suggestions for what I should read or what I should google?

Comment: The home of Dirac's gamma matrices is the theory where QM and SR were made to coexist. So unfortunately I  to no think that you can understand how gamma matrices are used in SR without touching QM.

Comment: "spacetime algebra"

Comment: @KurtG. - The gamma matrices just represent basis vectors for spacetime; they make perfect sense in SR without QM. The only problem with ordinary vectors, represented as column matrices, is that they can't be multiplied together. But vectors can be multiplied in geometric algebra. Of course square matrices can also be multiplied, and the two algebras are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

The gamma matrices were first introduced by Dirac to explain the quantum behaviour of electrons, so I think it is natural that most Google searches return quantum mechanics results. I am a physicist by training, so take my recommendation with a pinch of salt.

I like [Geometric Algebra for Physicists](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometric-algebra-for-physicists/FB8D3ACB76AB3AB10BA7F27505925091) by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby. Chapter 5 (Relativity and spacetime) is dedicated to the Clifford algebra of spacetime and is a  pretty much self-contained introduction to relativity in this context. The book also covers quantum theory if you are interested later.